# JavaScript - formatMoney - Como usar

Tags: javascript

Como eu faço para meu input ficar com as casas decimais....

preciso que ele formate no #total_compra

segue codigo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#evento_quantidade").change(function() {
var qtd = $(this).val();
var valor = $("#precoSoma").val();
var calculo = qtd * valor;
$("#total_compra").val(calculo);

 });

 String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
    var v = this;

    if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
    }

    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

    return v;
  };
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar `toFixed` , segundo a sua documentação¹ ele :

> Converte um número em string, deixando somente dois decimais.

Mas é claro, que você pode formatar para mais casas decimais se quiser. Exemplo :

```
  var valor = 2000.9001
  valor.toFixed(3) //retorna 2000.900 (arredondamento)
  valor.toFixed(2) //retorna 200.90
  valor.toFixed(7) //retorna 2489.9001000 (preenchimento)
```

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas como eu aplico isso no meu codigo?

Comment: Olhe esse exemplo : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tofixed

Comment: boa lek mto obg.... resolvido